# Using CDBExpression With CDBCriteria In findAll

Tags: yii

I am trying to generate and execute the following sql through CActiveRecord:

```
SELECT * FROM `bucket` `t` 
WHERE bkt_user = unhex('A4FF2131E00C4696837689FCAAAC7DD2');
```

I came up with this:

```
$uuid = 'A4FF2131E00C4696837689FCAAAC7DD2';
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$expression = new CDbExpression(
                    'unhex(:value)', 
                    array(':value'=>$uuid,));
$criteria->addCondition("bkt_user = :exp");
$criteria->params = array(':exp' => $expression);
$buckets = Bucket::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

The code executes without error or exception but does not return results as expected. A little debugging revealed that the snippet above generates the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `xpg_bucket` `t` WHERE bkt_user = :exp
```

and AFAIK only one `CDbCommandBuilder::bindValue` where `:exp` is bound to `unhex(:value)`. There is no parameter binding done for `:value`. This is happening in `CDbCommandBuilder::createFindCommand`. `CDbCommandBuilder::createInsertCommand`, on the other hand seems to take care of a value itself being a `CDbExpression` and generated the appropriate `bindValue's`.

`CDbExpression's` documentation contains:

```
* CDbExpression is mainly used in {@link CActiveRecord} as attribute values.
* When inserting or updating a {@link CActiveRecord}, attribute values of      
* type CDbExpression will be directly put into the corresponding SQL statement
* without escaping.
```

Does this mean CDbExpression is not meant to be used with CDbCriteria in findAll()? If yes, what is the alternative?

Comment: Have you tried `Bucket::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('bkt_user'=>new CDbExpression(.....))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it turns out all that circus is not required. The following works with `findAll`:

```
$criteria->addCondition('bkt_user = unhex(:value)');
$criteria->params = array(':value'=>'665730BDEDA7489383E2519DB5DE6D60');
$buckets = Bucket::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Be aware that the same will not work with `add` or `update` operations.